# Representing an Array( String[] ) as String CSV with Ranges

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an array of String that contain numbers(*unsigned integers*) padded with an arbitrary number of zeros, for example :

```
[ 0001, 0002, 0003, 0005,0007, 0010,0011,0012,0013,0014, 0015 ]
```

i want to convert the array into a representing string, the representing string should aggregate adjacent values with a range representation ( `0000-0003` ) and non-adjacent values as comma separated values, so for example the above string array should be represented as follow representing string :

```
0001-0003, 0005, 0007, 0010-0015
```

What is the best/simplest/more readable way to do it (without writing a tons of code :-) ) ?

Thanks.

Comment: hmm, that sounds like homework :)

Comment: No, i want to do it in a toString() method of a class, i have implemented something, but with a tons of code ... I would know if there is a better/smarter way .

Comment: What do you mean by "without writing tons of code?"

Comment: @ templatetypedef : I mean : what is the more concise way ? I want to put it in a toString() method ...

Comment: Is your input always sorted like above?

Comment: Tons of code? a straightforward implementation would be a loop containing about 4 to 6 lines of code.

Comment: "numbers" == ints or are floating point values possible? Is order guaranteed in the input?

Comment: No, not ever sorted could be also unsorted ...

Comment: with numbers i mean unsigned integers, sorry for not being accurate.

Comment: If you have existing code you should post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the requirements correctly then following code should work for you: (hope it is not really a `tons of code :-)`)

```
String[] arr = new String[] {"0001", "0020", "0002", "0003", "0019", "0005", "0007",
                             "0010", "0018", "0011", "0012", "0013", "0014", "0015"};
Map<Integer, String> m = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
for (String s : arr)
    m.put(new Integer(s), s);
Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> it;
Integer prev = -1;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
boolean isCont = false;
for (it=m.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Entry<Integer, String> entry = it.next();
    if (prev == -1)
        sb.append(entry.getValue());
    else if (entry.getKey() == (prev+1))
        isCont = true;
    else if (entry.getKey() > (prev+1)) {
        if (isCont)
            sb.append('-').append(m.get(prev)).append(", ");
        else
            sb.append(", ");
        sb.append(entry.getValue());
        isCont = false;
    }
    prev = entry.getKey();
}
if (isCont)
    sb.append('-').append(m.get(prev));
System.out.println(sb);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0001-0003, 0005, 0007, 0010-0015, 0018-0020
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, of course everyone has different taste.

```
    String[] a = { "0001", "0002", "0003", "0005", "0010" , "0011" , "0012" , "0013" , "0014", "0015", "0017" };

    String out = new String();
    String curStart = null;
    String curEnd = null;
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if (curStart == null) curStart = a [i];
        if ( a.length != i+1 
             && Integer.parseInt(a[i])+1 == Integer.parseInt(a[i+1])) {
            curEnd = a[i+1];
        } else {
            if (!out.equals("")) out+=", ";
            out+=""+curStart;
            if (curEnd != null) out+="-"+curEnd;
            curStart = null;
            curEnd = null;              
        }

    }

    System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: Will it work with **unsorted** input array as stated by OP in one of the comments?

Answer (score -1):

I would do it by treating every string as its own range, unioning adjacent ones together, and specializing my `Range.toString()` implementation for the case of a single element on its own.  Something like:

```
class Range {
  int low;
  int high;
  public Range(int elem) { this.low = elem; this.high = elem;}
  private Range(int low, int high) { this.low=low; this.high=high;}
  public Range tryMerge(Range other) { 
    if(high + 1 == other.low) {
      return new Range(low, other.high);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  public String toString() {
    return (low == high) ? Integer.toString(low) : low + "-" + high;
  }
}
```

with possibly some more stuff involved in the padding.